# .htaccess redirect to another domain using wildcard subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have looked around here all day, and although I have seen similar questions and I have managed to get a partial answer to my question, I am still missing one major part.

The thing I am trying to do is, to have dynamic subdomains (for instance username.mydomain.dk) to use within my system.

What I have managed so far:

1. Change DNS to support the wildcard, *.mydomain.dk
2. Make .htaccess redirect from my main domain (www.simon-smith.dk)
3. Successfully view the mydomain.dk page

Now the problem here is, that I have a few websites sharing the same IP address. www.simon-smith.dk is the main domain and mydomain.dk is also on this IP. Therefore when requesting the *.mydomain.dk I will get to www.simon-smith.dk first. From here I have added the following in my .htaccess:

```
# *.mydomain.dk redirectd
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.dk/?subrequest=%1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Here I am using the P flag to get to the other domain, but apparently this blocks the rewrite rules on mydomain.dk, which are as follows:

```
# match those that do not have language code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/[a-z]{2}/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]

# match those that DO have a language code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/js/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
```

I can access the subrequest parameter from the url without any problem, but the url parameter is not registered any longer.

Is there a way to use .htaccess to do this redirect, or will I have to get a webserver with mydomain.dk as the main domain to have the redirect done properly?

Answer (score 0):

Having dug a bit further and used some good ol' trial and error I found my mistake.

On my main domain, www.simon-smith.dk, I simply had to append the correct request uri for it to work, thus doing as follows:

```
# *.mydomain.dk redirectd
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.dk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.dk/$1?subrequest=%1 [P,L,QSA]
```